# Search box in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

I am working on a php script were I want to highlight the results.

I have the following code:

```
echo "<align='.left.'><a href='$link'><h1 style='.color:black.'> $title</h1></a><p>$desc</p></align>";
```

Here i want to highlight the anything that is replaced by `$title`. But I can't get the result highlighted. please help

Comment: i have the following code:  echo "<align='.left.'><a href='$link'><h1 style='.color:black.'> $title</h1></a><p>$desc</p></align>";

Answer (score 2):

Output HTML tags to enphasize that text. You can use HTML tags like `<em>` or `<strong>` for emphasis. They will have a default markup (italic and bold respectively), but you can change that through CSS.

```
echo "
   <align='.left.'>
     <a href='$link'>
       <h1 style='.color:black.'> 
         <em>$title</em>
      </h1>
     </a>
   <p>$desc</p></align>";
```

By the way, there are other issues in you HTML too. `<align='.left.'>` is not valid, and `style='.color:black.'` won't work either. It seems you need a little more practise with HTML and CSS too.

For example, see a syntaxically (html/css) correct version :

```
echo "
   <p class=\"text-left\">
     <a href=\"$link\">
       <h1 style=\"color:black\"> 
         <em>$title</em>
      </h1>
     </a>
    </p>
   <p class=\"text-left\">$desc</p>";
```

with a css file defining:

```
.text-left { text-align:left }
```

- The dotted css class notation is a css selector. Use it in css class definition, or as jquery selector (javascript DOM library)
- In HTML, it is preferable to use double qutoe over single quotes to define attributes
- Update your knowlegde in HTML5 over deprecated versions, and CSS3 over older ones.

Comment: thanks. But could show provide me with a code that could help me with echo and css. I need to make a website for my college project.